# Regular Expression to find string between two characters

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a REGEX to find the string between `\` and `>` in the following input :

```
\\RANDOM\APPLE\BOB\GEORGE\MIKE\TOM >>\\TEST\TEST2\TEST3\TEST\TEST\JOHN.
```

Desired Output:TOM

I've been able to create  `([^>]+)` to isolate the first section of the string before the first `>` . I just can't seem to figure out how to expand on this and isolate TOM.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: Try `[^\\>]+(?=\s>>)`, see https://regex101.com/r/R03825/1

Comment: Regex engines in different languages have different capabilities.  Can you add either a tag or edit your question to specify the language you are using.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew , your solution worked

Comment: You need to do a web search on `lookahead`  and `lookbehind assertions`.  They are very useful in situations like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
\\([^\\>]+?) >>
```

Regex [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6e2dEG/4)

In javascript:

```js
let regex = /\\([^\\>]+?) >>/

// Note \\ is required for literal \ in js
let str = "\\\\RANDOM\\APPLE\\BOB\\GEORGE\\MIKE\\TOM >>\\\\TEST\\TEST2\\TEST3\\TEST\\TEST\\JOHN.";

match = str.match(regex);

console.log(match[1]); //TOM
```

Answer (score 1):

This should works:

```
[^\\\s>]+(?=\s*>)
```

[Demo:](https://regex101.com/r/R03825/4)

It will works even if the desired match has one or more  > after it and if has one or more whitespaces before >.

I mean: this regex will match TOM from all this strings:

```
\\RANDOM\APPLE\BOB\GEORGE\MIKE\TOM  >\\TEST\TEST2\TEST3\TEST\TEST\JOHN.
\\RANDOM\APPLE\BOB\GEORGE\MIKE\TOM  >>\\TEST\TEST2\TEST3\TEST\TEST\JOHN.
\\RANDOM\APPLE\BOB\GEORGE\MIKE\TOM>>\\TEST\TEST2\TEST3\TEST\TEST\JOHN.
```